# Parsing token value from gitlab-runner output containing ANSI escape attributes

Tags: linux, bash, grep

Currently i'm trying to catch a token from `gitlab-runner list`, which outputs something like that:

```
Listing configured runners                          ConfigFile=/etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml
Ursain Bolt      Executor=docker Token=abcdef678901234567890123456789 URL=https://my.gitlab.com
```

I am searching for the existence of a Token: `Token=abcdef678901234567890123456789`.

I tried several patterns (i'm familiar with regular expressions), the one i'd prefer to use looks as follows:

```
gitlab-runner list 2>&1 >/dev/null | grep -E 'Token=[a-f0-9]{30}'
```

> I redirect stderr to stdout since it seems `gitlab-runner` prints to stdout. Not piping `stdout` to `/dev/null` makes no difference here.

This pattern does not match.

I tried sucessfully (grep returned `0`) the following matches:

- `[a-f0-9]+`
- `([a-f0-9])+'`
- `([a-f0-9]){30}`
- `Token`
- `Token.`

However, the following matches **did not** work (grep returned `1`):

- `(Token.[a-f0-9]){30}`
- `Token=[a-f0-9]{30}`
- `Token=`
- `Token\=`

What am i missing, why does the regular combination of both patterns (`Token` and `[a-f0-9]{30}`) with an equal sign not work?

---

#### Raw Gitlab-Runner Output

```
bash-4.3# gitlab-runner list 2>&1 >/dev/null
Listing configured runners                          ConfigFile=/etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml
Ursain Bolt      Executor=docker Token=abcdef678901234567890123456789 URL=https://my.gitlab.com
```

#### Partial Hexdump *Update*

```
...
000000a0: 2045 7865 6375 746f 721b 5b30 3b6d 3d64   Executor.[0;m=d
000000b0: 6f63 6b65 7220 546f 6b65 6e1b 5b30 3b6d  ocker Token.[0;m
000000c0: 3d65 6466 3834 3062 3436 6166 6434 3333  =edf840b46afd433
...
```

---

#### Version Numbers

```
bash-4.3# cat /etc/alpine-release
3.6.2

bash-4.3# bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.3.48(1)-release (x86_64-alpine-linux-musl)

bash-4.3# grep --version
grep (GNU grep) 3.0
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

---

Trying to reproduce this by echoing the output doesn't seem to work, grep matches the pattern as intended.

Comment: Works for me, grep v3.1: `echo Token=abcdef678901234567890123456789 | grep -E 'Token=[0-9a-f]{30}'`

Comment: Thank you very much @BartFriederichs - i should have mentioned that i tries echoing & grepping on my work-cmdline, too and there it works. I assume it might be caused by the redirection.

Comment: Don't you throw everything to `/dev/null` when doing `2>&1 >/dev/null` ? Do you get any result *without* the `grep`?

Comment: @florianb: Are you searching only on `stderr` stream? Because you are suppressing `stdout` fully by re-directing it to NULL

Comment: Yes, currently i'm suppressing `stdout` since it is unused by the command.

Comment: @florianb please post an actual output of `gitlab-runner list 2>&1 >/dev/null`

Comment: You are throwing everything (both stdout  and stderr )to /dev/null. So grepping on an empty string will return nothing.

Comment: @BhawandeepSingla: Your claim is wrong. OP is re-directing `stderr` to `stdout`

Comment: @Inian , and this stdout is redirecting to /dev/null , right ?

Comment: @BhawandeepSingla: Not it is only suppressing stdout to null

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using `GNU grep` use the PCRE library that comes with it. The `-P` flag enables it and `-o` flag returns only the matched group than the entire line. The `\K` is a reserved character to indicate ignore the string in the matched string upto that part.

```
grep -Po 'Token=\K[a-f0-9]{30}'
```

The problem with `grep -E 'Token=[a-f0-9]{30}'` is it will return the entire line matching the regex and *not* the matching group alone, since the string you are looking for is part of a line with other words. You can of-course use the `-o` flag in your original expression, but it would still return  `Token=abcdef678901234567890123456789`.

---

As a side note, you might want to ensure in which output stream your `Token=` string is available, because by your current re-direction `2>&1 > /dev/null` you are suppressing the entire `stdout` to null stream and re-directing only `stderr` to console and `grep` is acting only on that.

#### Update

So if your problem is with [ANSI escape sequences](http://ascii-table.com/ansi-escape-sequences.php), you need to clean your output with `sed` or any tools of your choice and apply the `grep` regex filter, something like

```
gitlab-runner list 2>&1 >/dev/null | s/.\[0;m//g | grep -Po 'Token=\K[a-f0-9]{30}'
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast response but it doesn't work either: `bash-4.3# gitlab-runner list 2>&1 >/dev/null | grep -Po 'Token=\K[a-f0-9]{30}'; echo $?
1`

Comment: @florianb: Can you show us `grep --version`? And what exactly is your output needed `Token=abcdef678901234567890123456789` or just `abcdef678901234567890123456789`

Comment: Could it be a problem with special characters, as they are somewhat dependent on shell and also a program. Maybe you can try to escape the '[]' and '{}' -characters to see if it works? In some situations even equal sign needs to be escaped.

Comment: @Inian thank you very much for your skillful response. I'd prefer catching key and value for explicity. For now i'll go with just matching the token. However, i stay curious why this happens.

Comment: @Inian - i added a hexdump - this weird command uses subsequent ansi escape attributes. :(

Comment: Most of the git commands provide a flag for suppressing colorization of output (eg `--color=never`) to solve this problem.  If `gitlab-runner` does not provide such an option, you should file a feature request.  If it does, you should use it!

Answer (score 0):

I fetched a hexdump of the output (using `gitlab-runner list 2>&1 >/dev/null | xxd` [xxd should be shipped with vim]. It turned out, that `gitlab-runner` adds [Ansi Escape Sequences](http://ascii-table.com/ansi-escape-sequences.php) `.[0;m` before every equal sign:

```
...
000000a0: 2045 7865 6375 746f 721b 5b30 3b6d 3d64   Executor.[0;m=d
000000b0: 6f63 6b65 7220 546f 6b65 6e1b 5b30 3b6d  ocker Token.[0;m
000000c0: 3d65 6466 3834 3062 3436 6166 6434 3333  =edf840b46afd433
...
```

The finally working pattern is `Token.{5}=[a-f0-9]{30}`.

Comment: You should not customize the `grep` logic to suit the escape sequences. A nice way would be to clean up the escape sequences so that the normal regex would work fine

Comment: something like `gitlab-runner list 2>&1 >/dev/null | sed 's/[\x01-\x1F\x7F]//g' | grep -Po 'Token=\K[a-f0-9]{30}'`

Comment: Good point @Inian - thank you - put it into your answer i'll accept it.

Comment: Answer updated! let know if it worked so I can modify the `sed` logic

Comment: @Inian the sed-pattern is way too hungry - it also strips regular characters.

Comment: I assumed it - i stick with `s/.\[0;m//g`.. :)

Comment: Yeah. Thanks! Updated my answer for the same